# strlen show wrong the number of array's elements

Tags: c++

```
void main() {
char str1[4] = { 'A','B','C','D' }; 
char str2[3] = { 'A','B','D' }; 
cout << strlen(str2) 


}
```

the results is 31, and I don't know why it happens

Comment: You don't have a null terminator at the end of str2 so the strlen function runs off through memory until it finds one.

Comment: I think you want `std::size()`, *not* `strlen`.

Comment: The "str" in `strlen` stands for **string**, and refers to a C-style nul-terminated string. The string must end with `'\0'`.

Comment: Also, `main` is required to return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Did you read the instructions on how `strlen()` works in the manual?

Answer (score 0):

You need nul-terminators on your C-style strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main() {
  char str1[4+1] = { 'A','B','C','D', '\0' }; // same as = "ABCD"
  char str2[3+1] = { 'A','B','D', '\0' };  // same as = "ABD"
  std::cout << std::strlen(str2) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C strings (as in arrays of chars) by standard are arrays which terminating character is '\0'.
When you assign a string like this:

```
char* a = "hello";
```

it's equivalent to:

```
char a[6] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

This kind of string works with strlen and similar (strcpy, strthis, strthat).

In C++ you should rather use the type String that you get including string. It's a class and you can use the functions of that class

```
#include <string>
... 
std::string a = "hello";
int size = a.size();
```

When you do `strlen` of an array (actually the address for the first character), the strlen function iterates in your memory until it finds a \0, even if it goes out of your array and into whatever other data is in your memory.
The 31 you got means your strlen was going on for 31 times the size of a char in your memory before it finally met a \0 byte.